# Symfony3 and NelmioCors - on POST it does not work

Tags: symfony, cors, http-headers, nelmiocorsbundle

I'm using NelmioCorsBundle under Symfony3 with the following setup:

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
        defaults:
            allow_credentials: false
            allow_origin: []
            allow_headers: []
            allow_methods: []
            expose_headers: []
            max_age: 0
            #hosts: []
            origin_regex: false
        paths:
            '^/api/':
                origin_regex: true
                allow_origin: ['*']
                allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth','Content-Type','X-Requested-With','Accept','Origin','Access-Control-Request-Method','Access-Control-Request-Headers','Authorization']
                allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
                expose_headers: []
                max_age: 3600
            '^/':
                origin_regex: true
                allow_origin: ['*']
                allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
                allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
                max_age: 3600
                hosts: ['^api\.']
```

which is working fine on `GET` but when I try to use with `POST` I get

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

What is wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but, in your paths there is `^/api/`, and in your error message there is only `http://localhost:8080`. Try change routing of your `POST` controller to `/api/something`. Let me know if it works.

---

**Update:**

I do not know Nelmio Cors enough, but if do you not planning use complex headers management i propose approach, that woks in my case (without external bundle):

Add listener: `src/AppBundle/Listentes/CorsListener.php`

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class CorsListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $responseHeaders = $event->getResponse()->headers;

        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

And register it in services: `app/config/services.yml`

```
services:
    app.cors_listener:
        class:      AppBundle\Listener\CorsListener
        tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

I know that is not exact answer for your question, but hope it can help.

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem that url is the origin not an api endpoint